# Вставка в БД записи адреса сайта

Tags: php, mysqli

Помогите пожалуйста вставить в бд (таблицу) вставить строку

```
'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];"','".$_SESSION[comment_mess_login]."'
```

Вот в эту строку, нужное место я пометил словом "сюда"

```
insert into comment (avtor,date,theme,login,message,avatar) values ('".$row['id']."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','"   ***СЮДА***"','".$_SESSION[comment_mess_login]."','".$_SESSION[comment_user_text]."','".$row['avatar']."')
```

Comment: Просто выдаёт ошибку неправильного синтаксиса

Comment: И будет выдавать, там же кавычки в строке. _Никогда_ не подставляйте текст непосредственно в запрос. Используйте привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Как выглядит сообщение об ошибке? В каких кавычках у вас запрос в двойных?

Comment: спасибо)))))))))))

Comment: +1 mike, Более того, никогда не используйте php. Ни какой другой язык, не славится дурным sql. Пока в php появились prepared statement, к тому времени сформировалась учебная база на неправильном sql, от которой уже не избавится никогда.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо экранировать урл перед вставкой в БД. например с помощью `mysql_real_escape_string`. Не экранированый урл всегда потенциальная SQL injection уязвимость.

Answer (score 0):

я решил использовать переменную $url  ($url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];)

и далее подставил переменную в запрос к бд

Вот решил решение:`insert into comment (avtor,date,theme,login,message,avatar) values ('".$row['id']."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$url."','".$_SESSION[comment_mess_login]."','".$_SESSION[comment_user_text]."','".$row['avatar']."'`